# How to access nested JSON in Google Tag Manager value collection in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, google-tag-manager

I'm using the GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK 3.10 with iOS 8.1/Swift/XCode 6.1.

I have a GTM container with a value collection macro, which has nested JSON, like this:

```
{
   "cat":
    {
        "legs": 4,
        "sound": "meow"
    },
    "dog":
    {
        "legs": 4,
        "sound": "woof"
    },
    "fox": 
    {
        "legs": 4,
        "sound": "?"
    }
}
```

How do I get the number of legs a dog has? I've tried (among other variations)
`container.stringForKey("dog.legs")`, where `container` is an instance of  `TAGContainer`, and that doesn't work.

If I inspect `container.stringForKey("dog")`, I get a string, `"{legs=4, sound=woof}"`. Unfortunately, I can't use the `.propertyList()` string method to get a dictionary from the string because there are commas instead of semicolons, and even if I replace the commas with semicolons, I run into issues if values have spaces in them. For instance, if I used `"woof woof"` instead of just `"woof"`, the `.propertyList()` method fails to parse a dictionary from the string. It's also not a valid JSON string so I can't use JSON parsing tools, either.

Is there a clean (or at least recommended) way to do this in Swift?